# Gradle copy task expand yaml file escape whole string

Tags: templates, gradle, yaml

I have the following gradle task:

```
processResources {
    inputs.properties(project.properties.findAll { it.value instanceof String })
    filesMatching("**/*.yaml") {
        filteringCharset = 'UTF-8'
        expand project.properties
    }
}
```

that I use to process a spring boot *application.yaml* file that contains variable placeholders.

How can I escape a whole log pattern without escaping every single special character, thus keeping the pattern clean?

application.yaml:

```
logging:
  pattern:
    console: %clr(%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}
```

Tried using slashy strings with no success:

1.Tried:

```
/%clr(%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}/
```

Error:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Failed to parse template script (your template may contain an error or be trying to use expressions not currently supported): startup failed:
SimpleTemplateScript8.groovy: 138: expecting '}', found 'HH' @ line 138, column 60.
   ATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S
                                 ^
```

2.Tried:

```
$/%clr(%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}/$
```

Error:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Failed to parse template script (your template may contain an error or be trying to use expressions not currently supported): startup failed:
SimpleTemplateScript10.groovy: 138: illegal string body character after dollar sign;
   solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 138, column 15.
       console: $/%clr(%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}/$
                 ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that your YAML files contains character which are interpreted as tokens by the `expand` method, relying on Groovy's `SimpleTemplateEngine`, you should use an alternative method like the `filter` methods.

[The documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:filtering_files) shows a number of examples of `filter`. By using the underlying Ant `ReplaceTokens` you might have better luck, as it uses `@token@` as the notation.